# Code is looking for attributes in the wrong class

Tags: python, python-3.8

This code's really unfinished, but it's getting there. I'm trying to organize the inputs of an item's name and price to a list, but I'm getting an error caused by the code looking for the _purchases attribute in the Item class instead of the Receipt class. What's causing this?

```
import datetime

class Item:
    def __init__(self,_name="None",_price=0,_taxable="no"):
        self._name=_name
        self._price=_price
        self._taxable=_taxable
    def __str__(self):
        base="{:-<20}".format(self._name)+"{:->20}".format(self._price)
        return base
    def getPric(self):
        pass
    def getTax(self):
        pass

class Receipt:
    def __init__(self,_tax_rate=0,_purchases=""):
        self._tax_rate=_tax_rate
        self._purchases=_purchases
    def __str__(self):
        pass
    def additem(self):
        list=self._purchases.append(self)
        
#Main Program
if __name__=="__main__":
    loop="no"
    print("Welcome to Receipt Creator")
    while True:
        name=input("Enter Item name: ")
        price=float(input("Enter Item Price: "))
        taxable=input("Is the item taxable (yes/no): ")
        product=Item(name,price,taxable)
        print(product)
        print(Receipt.additem(product))
        print(list)
        loop=input("Add another item (yes/no): ")
        if loop=="yes":
            continue
        else:
            break
    print("----- Receipt",str(datetime.datetime.now()),"-----")
    print(list)
```

EDIT: Here's the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\main.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(Receipt.additem(product))
  File "C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\main.py", line 23, in additem
    list=self._purchases.append(self)
AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute '_purchases'
```

Comment: Please show the error including full traceback.

Comment: `list = self._purchases.append(self)` that doesn’t seem right.

Comment: Here: `Receipt.additem(product)` you're calling a `Receipt` method with `product` as `self`. Whatever you were trying to do, that is not the way to do it.

Comment: Well, by combining those two things, it might actually work by accident.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I added the traceback

Comment: If you examine my answer, it explains why you are getting the seemingly confusing error about it **'looking for the _purchases attribute in the Item class'**. It is using the passed in `product` which is an `Item` as the `self`. The details are in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a clear idea of what you have, but the execution has a lot of room for improvement.

Let's not touch the `Item` class, since that is not the one that is causing troubles. But as regards to `Receipt`, let's create a list for `purchases` to hold the purchases, and let's define a method (`add_item`) to populate that list:

```
class Receipt:
    def __init__(self, tax_rate=0):
        self.tax_rate = tax_rate
        self.purchases = []

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.purchases.append(item)
```

Now, you definitely need to instantiate that `Receipt` class (as opposite as you were doing), so in your main loop you should have something like:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    print("Welcome to Receipt Creator")
    rcpt = Receipt()
    while True:
        name = input("Enter Item name: ")
        price = float(input("Enter Item Price: "))
        taxable = input("Is the item taxable (yes/no): ")
        product = Item(name, price, taxable)
        print(product)
        rcpt.add_item(product)
        print(rcpt.purchases)
        loop = input("Add another item (yes/no): ")
        if loop == "yes":
            continue
        else:
            break
    print(rcpt.purchases)
```

Now, some things to note in your previous code:

- Unless you want to let other people know that an attribute is meant to be used only inside the definition of a class, there's no actual need to use a leading underscore to name an attribute.
- You were trying to print `list`. Keep in mind that `list` is a builtin class, so try name your attributes using something different (you can use a trailing underscore, actually. Like `list_`). Moreover, you were trying to print the `list` attribute that you had defined in your `additem()` method, without having instantiated the `Receipt` class and ask the class for it (with something like `instance.list_`).
- In your `__init__` method of the `Receipt` class that you had defined, you had a default value for `_purchases` to be `""` (an empty string), but that attribute was intended to be a list. (since you were trying to use the `append()` method after in your `additem()` method), which makes no sense at all.

Comment: now I'm getting
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: You're not using the `add_item()` method that I provided or you haven't changed the `__init__()` method of the class (most likely)

Answer (score 1):

@revliscano has an answer that fixes your issues. I will leave the answer to him. I am just going to explain why you got the somewhat confusing error that you got.

**looking for _purchases attribute in the Item class**

In your class `Receipt` you have:

```py
class Receipt:
    ...
    def additem(self):
        list=self._purchases.append(self)
```

and were later calling it with:

```py
        product=Item(name,price,taxable)
        print(product)
        print(Receipt.additem(product))
```

So you are calling `additem()` on the `Receipt` class, not on an instance of that class. Normally when you call an instance method, the instance you are calling it with is passed in as the `self` by python. It did not have an instance since you called it on the class itself, and as a result under the hood python was passing the `product` in as the `self` variable because python was treating it like a call on a static class method though it was supposed to be an instance method (i.e. no `cls` or `self` arg, and just pass the given arg to the method). So because you called it like `Receipt.additem(product)`, the `product` was passed as the `self`.

That meant that when it tried to do the `self._purchases.append(self)` it was like it was trying to do `product._purchases.append(product)` and so it was trying to find the `_purchases` attribute on `product`. Since `product` is an instance of the `Item` class, that is how you get your confusing error message.

Comment: Well explained. I struggle a little bit still to make myself clear in English.